# Set values in a new column based on a boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a data frame and two dictionaries as follows:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
x = {'a':'a'}
y = {'b':'b'}
```

Now I would like to perform an operation that adds a new column C such that each cell in C stores x when A >=2 and B >= 2, and stores y otherwise. The resulting data frame should be equivalent to:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[{'b':'b'}, {'a':'a'}, {'a':'a'}]})
```

I have tried many different approaches and nothing has worked so far. This is a toy example, while the real data frame will have many rows and columns and more complex conditions might be used. The end goal is to prepare a data frame for visualization with plotly by storing all the necessary info for visualization (such as marker definitions) as additional columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`np.where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
a['C'] = np.where((a.A >= 2) & (a.B >= 2), x, y)

   A  B           C
0  1  4  {'b': 'b'}
1  2  5  {'a': 'a'}
2  3  6  {'a': 'a'}
```

To explain this a bit since you say your real data is more complex, **`np.where`** will:

> Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition

So simply create your condition, and then identify what `x` and `y` need to be based on the result of the condition.  If you have more than two possible options, and multiple conditions, then you should look at [**`np.select`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Here is the equivalent **`np.select`** for the sake of demonstration:

```
conds = [(a.A >=2) & (a.B >=2)]
choices = [x]

np.select(conds, choices, default=y)
# array([{'b': 'b'}, {'a': 'a'}, {'a': 'a'}], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. There's one small snag. The actual object I'm trying to store is not quite a dictionary, it's one of these - go.Marker(color='rgba(76, 175, 80,1.0)', size=5, symbol='square') (which is a plotly object). np.where doesn't seem to like when I use this rather than the dictionary and complains with - ValueError: invalid __array_struct__. Any ideas why the dictionary works and this doesn't?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting dilemma.  I am not familiar with plotly so I'm, not entirely sure.  I'm guessing it doesn't know how to put the type into a numpy array.  Does `plotly` allow you to dump your markers to dictionaries and then parse them back in somehow?